# How to add product image as a background image in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to WooCommerce and I am creating a section with 2 products, But I want to add the text and add to card button over the product image, so I need the product image to be as a background, How can I do that? can I do it with css or I need JS? thanks

I am not very good in JS :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware this is not a free coding service. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the How to Ask page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need JS, the adjustment is done with CSS, you need to add the following attributes to the following classes.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img {
    background-image: url(/your/image/url);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```